In-place operation causes a memory leak. Why?
I have the following piece of code:
eigvecs = torch.randn(n, b, dtype=eigval_approximations.dtype, device=eigval_approximations.device)
eigvecs /= torch.linalg.norm(eigvecs, dim=0)

for _ in range(iterations):
    eigvecs = torch.linalg.solve(mats - eigval_approximations * identity, eigvecs.T).T
    eigvecs /= torch.linalg.norm(eigvecs, dim=0)

It is part of loss calculation in PyTorch, and it causes GPU OOM after a few epochs.
eigvecs is re-initialized at every training/validation step, and it is of the same size at each step. It exists in a very short-lived scope.
Changing this piece of code such that it avoids in-place division (/=) eliminates the memory leak.
Why was there a memory leak due to an in-place operation in the first place? I don’t see any reason for this.
Is it expected in Python, or might it be an implementation detail of or a bug in PyTorch?

Are you watching your GPU usage and actually seeing it grow each iteration, or are you just assuming it is because the out of memory doesn't occur on the first iteration?

@Joe Yes, it gradually grows at each step.

Try printing the dimensions of eigvecs each iteration.

@Joe It is the same at each training/validation step and iteration. My hunch is that it has something to do with the reference counts of each new eigvecs. Very weird, though, because it exists in a very short-lived scope.

I think it is deeply linked to the way the __itruediv__ operator (called when "/=" is written) is implemented on the Tensor class. As the inner mechanics of pytorch is written in C++, It may be a little more complicated than just looking at the python code. The tensor is defined here : https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/csrc/tensor/python_tensor.cpp if you want more information.
